# FOSUserBundle forbid editing the username

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

How to forbid editing the username in FOSUserBundle?

Now i can enter profile editing page and change username. How to allow this only for ROLE_ADMIN only for example?

But to allow edit email in profile.

Found solution:

```
class ProfileFormType extends BaseType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->remove('username');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'goock_user_profile';
}
}
```

Is it secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to allow only ROLE_ADMIN to edit a form field, you'll need to pass the "security.context" service into your form type, and then do something like the following

```
if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
   $builder->add('username');
}

//or if username is already added

if (!$this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
   $builder->remove('username');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure by restricting what role can access: $builder->add('username'); that a malicious user cannot post the username field manually and change their username?

Comment: The only way this could happen is if you have extra fields enabled on your form.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#extra-fields-message